# Markov measure on cylinders

Tags: measure-theory, dynamical-systems, markov-chains, ergodic-theory

If T is a Markov map with associated partition $\{A_i\}$ and  $A_{i_0i_1i_2...i_{n-1}}$ an n-cylinder, i.e.
$A_{i_0i_1i_2...i_{n-1}}:=A_{i_0}\cap T^{-1}A_{i_1}\cap T^{-2}A_{i_2}\cap ...\cap T^{-(n-1)}A_{i_{n-1}}.$

It should be true that
$$\mu(A_{i_0i_1i_2...i_{n-1}})=\mu(A_{i_0})P_{i_0i_1}P_{i_1i_2}...P_{i_{n-2}i_{n-1}}.$$ Where $P_{ij}$ is the transition matrix associated to T. i.e. $$P_{ij}=\frac{\mu(T^{-1}A_j\cap A_i)}{\mu(A_i)}$$

This would be a necessary part of showing metric conjugacy between the Markov map and the associated subshift of finite type with associated so-called "Markov measure" defined exactly as above.

Is there a simple induction proof of this? Do we need that $\mu$ is $T$-invariant? The base case (and the 1-cylinder case) is clear, and I have tried to use some total probability type arguments, but something is eluding me and I have a sneaking suspicion that I'm missing something silly.

Comment: Draw the intersections: it should help you showing that the property follows easily from the Markov property and the invariance of the measure.

Comment: I still haven't got it but this did help me realize that it's not this particular problem that I don't understand. If the Markov property is really a "markov" property, it really should mean that $\mu(x_{n+1}\in A_{i_{n+1}}|x_n\in A_{i_n},x_{n-1}\in A_{i_{n-1}},...)=\mu(x_{n+1}|x_n)$. I don't see immediately how this follows from the definition of a Markov partition, and I feel like it should be straightforward

edit: I can see how the invariance is related to the autonomy of the corresponding markov chain, I can also see how once you have this property  the proof is clear.

Comment: It does. As I wrote: draw the intersections (that's the best hint). PS: you should not use the notation $\mu(x_{n+1}|x_n)$, no need to talk about conditional expectations, in dynamics we usually don't use this peculiar notation from probability theory.